# Vertically center UILabel in parent UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, uilabel

How do I vertically (y-axis) center a UILabel inside its parent UIView without changing the horizontal position of the UILabel?

The following is not it (it changes the x-axis):

```
[self.label setCenter:CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.height / 2)]
```

Again, I am looking to center along the y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint center = self.label.center;
center.y = view.frame.size.height / 2;
[self.label setCenter:center];
```

**Swift Answer..**

```
var center : CGPoint = self.titleLbl.center
        center.y = self.frame.size.height / 2
        self.titleLbl.center = center
```

Comment: No. This didn't do it.

Comment: What did it do? As in what was the output?

Comment: It changed nothing. But then I realized that the math was a bit off. But your general idea is correct so thank you. The correct math is `CGFloat padding = (parent.frame.size.height-self.label.frame.size.height)/2;
    center.y +=padding;`

Answer (score 1):

I would rather recommend to apply autolayout constraints in this case. The below constraint will align is vertically in center of parent view.In 2nd constraint i am keeping a value of 20 as x coordinate. You can replace it with your own value.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraintY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view
                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[view addConstraint:constraintY];
NSLayoutConstraint *constraintX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0];
[view addConstraint:constraintX];
```

Comment: IMHO save yourself the trouble and stay away from auto layout forever. It's hell enough trying to use inside interface builder, messing with it programmatically can only be a thousand times worse.